# Iterate over the files of a given folder - Bash

Tags: bash, loops

When I want to iterate over the files in a given folder I usually do:

```
for folder in $DIR/Runfirstall/*
```

But I found this in some code:

```
for folder in $DIR/!(Runfirstall)/
```

Does it do the same?

Comment: A trailing `/` only returns directories. This assigns *all dirs not names RunInstall* to `$folder`. On the other hand, `for folder in $DIR/Runfirstall/*` will include files (& stuff...) as well as directories.

Answer (score 2):

No. `!(...)` is an extended glob pattern which needs `shopt -s extglob`. It matches anything but `Runfirstall`, i.e. it will expand to all the directories under $DIR *except for* `Runfirstall`. It won't list anything under Runfirstall or any other subdirectory of $DIR.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
mkdir dir1 dir2
touch file1 file2
touch dir1/file1-{1..3}
mkdir dir1/dir1-{1..3}
touch dir1/dir1-{1..3}/file1-1-{1..2}

DIR=.

for f in "$DIR"/dir1/*   ; do echo "$f" ; done
echo '---'
shopt -s extglob
for f in "$DIR"/!(dir1)/ ; do echo "$f" ; done
```

Output:

```
./dir1/dir1-1
./dir1/dir1-2
./dir1/dir1-3
./dir1/file1-1
./dir1/file1-2
./dir1/file1-3
---
./dir2/
```